# What is the command to know IP that accessing our server with Iptables

Tags: iptables, ip, display

May I know what is the command that I should use to get the output of all IP & its frequent while they are accessing my server? I need this command to know the frequency of IP that access my server so that I can block the most frequent IP that access my server. Please help me since I am a newbie to Iptables

Comment: Have a look at `fail2ban` that may better suit you. Otherwise banning an IP just because of its frequency will give you a lot of false positives...

Answer (score 0):

Iptables is the command line interface to the linux firewall system, it does not record IP addresses uses and/or frequencies

If you want to see this kind of information you will need to use another tool, it's usualy done using a packet capture tool.

You could for example run tshark/tcpdump on the server, store the result in a pcap file and open it with wireshark on a desktop to get some statistics.